# Can i send push notification to specific application with rest api?

Tags: firebase, api, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can send specific or topic user to push notification with rest api.

But i need to send push notifcation to all of the user in a specific application using rest api.
Like i have dev applicaiton also production application.
So if i need to send notification to all dev user. how can i send it by rest api?

Can anyone give me the payload?

i have single user one.

```
{ 
                "to": "cyZTpu4xRVifkeTcPHGaOF:APA91bHWsKJU-81B8ZZubdJujmEJKIFcDy8lVM4XhXbliLTIFmOLR14ceqxWTYD5gj2L26yKSLyISkaV6NerQRKI-YoCgQMkeb_2Rw93a5EviKIJEuN-7O1M5vejzr0tSAzgf7IGUZoe",
                "notification": {
                    "title": "Rest api test",
                    "body": "Notification sent",
                    "sound": "Tri-tone"
                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "specific application"? How do you determine if a user is in a specific application?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: @DougStevenson specific mean i have dev user and production user
like i have android application id com.apps.prod also com.apps.dev .
so if i need to send notification to all dev user.
how can i send it by rest api?

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple solution, depending on your workflow, could be to subscribe each application to a dedicated topic, that reflects the app id (`com.apps.dev` to topic `dev`, `com.apps.prod` to topic `prod`).

You can then use the `topic` field in your REST request to target all of the devices running a specific application id.

If you need to target a specific topic *and* app id, you can use the `condition` field as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?hl=en#send-messages-to-topics). The following example will send the notification to all development apps subscribed to 'target-topic':

```json
{
    "condition": "'dev' in topics && 'target-topic' in topics"
}
```